# UIPageViewController page location dots appear overlapped?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I am having this issue where the dots in my PageViewController are appearing with a dot in-between two dots. When I save the pages and load them, then the pages appear with normal dots, the appropriate number of dots, and normal placement. Here is an image of what I am talking about.

[image]

Hierarchy debugger shows this image. Obviously the dots are appearing multiple times, behind one another. 
[image]

Here is the code that I use for the dots:

```
func configurePageControl() {
    pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY - 50,width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,height: 50))
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = storyPageViewControllers.count
    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
    self.pageControl.tintColor = UIColor.black
    self.pageControl.alpha = 0.5
    self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white
    self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black
    self.view.addSubview(pageControl)
}
```

configurePageControl() is called in the viewDidAppear. I tried moving it to the viewDidLoad, but it only showed one dot and didn't show more as I made new pages.

Here is my extension on the UIPageViewController class if you want to see how my pages are created:

```
extension BookPageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    guard let viewControllerIndex = storyPageViewControllers.index(of: viewController as! TemplateViewController) else { return nil }

    if viewControllerIndex == 0 { return nil } // Page won't scroll below first page.

    let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

    guard storyPageViewControllers.count > previousIndex else { return nil }
    currentPage = Double(previousIndex)

    return storyPageViewControllers[previousIndex]
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    guard let viewControllerIndex = storyPageViewControllers.index(of: viewController as! TemplateViewController) else { return nil }

    let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1
    let storyPageViewControllersCount = storyPageViewControllers.count

    guard storyPageViewControllersCount != nextIndex else { return nil }

    guard storyPageViewControllersCount > nextIndex else { return nil }
    currentPage = Double(nextIndex)
    return storyPageViewControllers[nextIndex]
}

// MARK: Delegate function
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    let pageContentViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers![0]
    self.pageControl.currentPage = storyPageViewControllers.index(of: pageContentViewController as! TemplateViewController)!
}

func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return storyPageViewControllers.count
}



func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    guard let firstViewController = viewControllers?.first,
        let firstViewControllerIndex = storyPageViewControllers.index(of: firstViewController as! TemplateViewController) else
    { return 0 }

    return firstViewControllerIndex
}
}
```

Comment: debug your view hierarchy and post an screenshot to see what is going on there

Comment: Thanks @ReinierMelian, I just put that image on.

Comment: check if you are calling this method  func configurePageControl() more than once

Comment: Thanks for your response. The only time I call that function is in the viewDidAppear, which would make sense that it would cause it to show up multiple times since I assume viewDidAppear shows up every time a new page is created. So I moved it to viewDidLoad, now the dot only shows up on the second page, but only as one dot. Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't call `configurePageControl()` on `viewDidAppear`, call it on `viewDidLoad`...  then just update the pageControl when a new page is added

Answer (score 2):

1- Definitely don't call configurePageControl() on viewDidappear. Is wrong, can give u bugs and weird user experience.

2- U r calling configurePageControl() 3 times. By chance do you have 3 viewController on your pageViewController?

Solutions:

*A:* I would create the pageViewController in Storyboard and just update the dots number just after u finish setting all ViewControllers.

*B:* Keep all as is BUT:

1- Move configurePageControl() to ViewDidLoad()

2- Leave it like this, with initial dots to 0

(tip 1: avoid using "self" when is not necessary)

(tip 2: avoid using frames, use constraints)

```
func configurePageControl() {
    pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 
    UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY - 50,width: 
    UIScreen.main.bounds.width,height: 50))
    pageControl.numberOfPages = 0
    pageControl.currentPage = 0
    pageControl.tintColor = UIColor.black
    pageControl.alpha = 0.5
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black
    view.addSubview(pageControl)
}
```

3- Just after u finish setting all viewControllers, update the pageViewControllers dots number

```
pageControl.numberOfPages = storyPageViewControllers.count
```

Notice it should work if placed here, but is not the right place. U can do it just for testing.

```
func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: 
    UIPageViewController) -> Int {
       pageControl.numberOfPages = storyPageViewControllers.count
       return storyPageViewControllers.count
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed that issue for me. I did everything you said and then I put the `pageControl.numberOfPages = storyPageViewControllers.count` in my updatePageViewController function that is called in my computed property. While that answered this question, maybe you can tell me what to do if my page index on my second page thinks that is the initial page. Any idea? Do I need to do a currentPage = storyPageViewController.count -1 or something?

Comment: Debug if you are setting the right number here. And don't set it anywhere else. In middle of something now if need more details let me know.
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {

    self.pageControl.currentPage = storyPageViewControllers.index(of: pageContentViewController as! TemplateViewController)!  ---HERE---
}

Comment: @Josh If you would do what I said - use the page control already included as part of UIPageViewController - you would get automatic syncing between the two.

Answer (score 2):

UIPageViewController already *has* a page control; all you have to do is show it (by implementing the two data source methods that do that). You shouldn't be adding *another* page control to it. The included page control already syncs itself to the page view controller. You're doing far more work than you should be doing.

Comment: I am not suggesting you change it in your code. I'm suggesting you throw your code away! What you're doing is a total waste of time. Just implement the two "Supporting a Page Indicator" methods listed in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontrollerdatasource) and you're good to go. You can still change the look of the page control using the appearance proxy (and you will probably want to do so).

Comment: Sounds good. I realized the dataSource methods I was using were outdated. I updated those and it seems to be fine. Do you have any suggestions regarding the dataSource required methods (viewControllerBefore and viewControllerAfter)? Or do they look ok?

Comment: I've tried to answer the question you actually asked. I hope you find my answer helpful. If you have a different question that's a real question, please ask a new question.